# Enviar mensajes de succes o error en c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola comunidad estoy trabajando en un proyecto con c# en mvc bien dentro de mi controlador están mis acciones de gradar , editar y eliminar lo que deseo es capturar los mensaje de error o success luego de cada acción tengo algo pero no me muestra en mi plantilla los mensajes lo hace en la url aquí mi código

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RegistroEditar(FormCollection form)
    {
        SEG_ROL_DTO oRol = new SEG_ROL_DTO
        {
            id_rol = Funciones.CheckInt(form["id_rol"]),
            nombre = form["nombre"],
            descripcion = form["descripcion"]
        };

        try
        {
            string estadoForm = oRol.id_rol > 0 ? "E" : "N";

            SegRolBL.Grabar(estadoForm, oRol);
            return RedirectToAction("Lista", "Rol");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException x)
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = x.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("RegistroEditar", "Rol", new { mensaje = x.Message, identificador = 1 });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RegistroEditar", "Rol", new { mensaje = e.Message, identificador = 2 });
        }
    }
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: buenas! lo que quieres es capturar los error en una vista tipo template? y lo suscess también? o a que terefieres?

Comment: Exacto eso es lo que deseo

Answer (score 0):

Si los Actions de cada `RedirectToAction` estan en tu controlador, lo que estas haciendo es redirigir al action correspondiente pasandole un objeto por parametro, lo que debes hacer en este caso es en cada action retornar una vista a la cual le pases un modelo correspondiente, para mostrar el mensaje.

ejemplo: 
para: `return RedirectToAction("RegistroEditar", "Rol", new { mensaje = x.Message, identificador = 1 });`

en tu controller debes tener el siguinete action:

`public ActionResult RegistriEditar(string mensaje, int identificador)`

Aquí puedes optar por dos opciones:

1. Utilizar el objeto dinamico ViewBag al cual puedes agregarle las dos propiedades correspondientes y luego con Razor mostrar en la vista:

   - Dentro del action en cuestion asignas los parametros a dos propiedades de dicho objeto de la siguiente manera:

   `public ActionResult RegistriEditar(string mensaje, int identificador)`
       `{`

   `ViewBag.Mensaje = mensaje;`

   `ViewBag.Identificador = identificador;`

   `return View();`

   `}`

y luego en la vista con Razor muestras de la siguiente manera el mensaje

```html
<div>
  @ViewBag.Mensaje
</div>
```

2. Para este caso puedes pasarle a la vista un modelo, una clase la cual en la vista tiene que especificar colocando en la parte superior de tu cshtml lo siguiente:

   @model MyModelName

Y previamente en el action debes retornar lo siguiente:

```
return View(new MyModelName(mensaje,identificador));
```

en la vista para utilizar el modelo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
@Model.Mensaje
```

Recuerda que el MyModelName debes definirla e implementarla

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.